# Altium Designer Rules: How to create paste rule for pads of specific component type?

Tags: altium, design-rules

I'm using **Altium Designer 20.0.9** to create a PCB to be assembled by the manufacturer with the exception of several components that I will add manually later. I do not want to have paste placed on the pad for these components. I see that the most obvious path is where I either set the component `Type` as `Standard (No BOM)`, or create a Variant and set a component as `Not Fitted` to identify these parts.

I'd like to create a rule to automatically prevent paste from being placed on these pads, based on the component `Type` (or `fitted` state). It seems as `ComponentType` or `IsNoBOMComponent` could be useful, but this checks against a component, rather than a child object, such as a pad. I think I need something akin to "`InComponentWithType`", or a way to find parent object membership.

- *Is there a way to query for pads based on a component's type (or fitted state)?*

Alternatively, am I better off to add `ClassName` parameters to these components and use `InComponentClass`? - it doesn't quite seem to be the best option and may be a bit more prone to mistakes.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It does make it hard to prototype if there is no solder on the pads

Comment: For adding a couple of additional components (QNF-56 and SOT23-8) that I couldn't get sourced during the PCBA process, I thought it would be easier to start with a flat surface (ENIG) and work from there. I know there would be risks in reflowing a second time, so I was considering manually applying paste, hot air and iron, as a starting point. Are there likely to be issues with this approach?

Comment: If you are manually applying paste with a stencil, no, better to have a flat surface (but the problem there is the stencil won't work unless you cut it smaller. If you are applying solder any other way its probably better to have solder there IMO

Comment: I don't think that I'd have a chance at stencilling it (even cut) due to the location and surrounding components. I wondered if any flux in the previously heated solder would be burned away making it more work.

Comment: not usually, most of the time the flux is cleaned off by the boardhouse

Comment: You can make separate footprints with no paste on the pads and assign the no-paste footprint to the desired components. Easier to keep track of the parts. If the parts don't have a thermal pad, you can hand-solder the parts.